# Remote validation not working in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, remote-validation

Here I have create form which consists customer email field for which I am trying to check whether the entered email already exits or not and if exist show email already exists message.
To do this i have tried to use remote validation but the problem is that its not showing any error even though email exists, it not even hitting the controller in `IsEmailExists` method which is used for remote validation 
Any help with my code will be a great help. Thank you
Below is my action in controller

```
    public JsonResult IsEmailExists(string CustomerEmail)
    {
        emedicineEntities _db = new emedicineEntities();
        return Json(!_db.Customers.Any(x => x.CustomerEmail == CustomerEmail), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Below is my metadata

```
namespace eMedicine.Model
{
    public class CustomerMetaDta
    {
        [Remote("IsEmailExists", "Customers", ErrorMessage = "EmailId already exists.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Emailw")]
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is my partial class

```
namespace eMedicine.Model
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaDta))]
    public partial class Customer
    {
    }
}
```

Below is my view consisting customer  email

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customers", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "register" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordHash, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordHash, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordHash, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Just a comment: the attribute '[Remote]` **does not** validate on server-side.

Comment: @redcaper71 Have tried by adding the `Remote` attribute directly to the `CustomerEmail` in `Customer` class, instead of using metadata?

Comment: @TanvirArjel that will disappear when that class is re-created so validation is done on metadata

Comment: @redcaper71  Please change the method signature as follows and let me know: `public JsonResult IsEmailExists([Bind(Prefix="Customer.CustomerEmail")] string CustomerEmail)`

Comment: @redcaper71 Any update? Has it worked for you?

Comment: @TanvirArjel no its not working

Comment: Electricity gone in my side! I see your Customer class is missing 'MetaDataType' attribute in your actual code. Please add this to Customer class as you shown in the question.

Comment: @TanvirArjel so whats the problem

Comment: @redcaper71 Please give the Team Viewer password again. Electricity has come in my side.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method signature as follows to include the `Bind Prefix` attribute/property.

```
public JsonResult IsEmailExists([Bind(Prefix="Customer.CustomerEmail")] string CustomerEmail)
{
    emedicineEntities _db = new emedicineEntities();
    return Json(!_db.Customers.Any(x => x.CustomerEmail == CustomerEmail), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now it should work!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what real problem with your source code, but i tried to reproduce in my side, it worked well.

Here are my source code.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerMetaDta
    {
        [Remote("IsEmailExists", "Customer", ErrorMessage = "EmailId already exists.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Emailw")]
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaDta))]
    public partial class Customer
    {

    }

    public partial class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult IsEmailExists(string CustomerEmail)
        {
            //emedicineEntities _db = new emedicineEntities();
            List<Customer> _db = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer { CustomerEmail  = "hien@gmail.com"},
                new Customer { CustomerEmail  = "hien1@gmail.com"}
            };
            return Json(!_db.Any(x => x.CustomerEmail == CustomerEmail), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        // GET: Customer
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml file:

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "register" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordHash, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordHash, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordHash, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

It jumps to method IsEmailExists() and this is result output
[image]

May be you missed setting

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not hitting the controller that suggests it isn't a problem with the actual validation logic, but more an issue with how you're addressing the server.

There are a few things to check:

#### Is your remote validation code available to the client at all?

The first thing to consider is could this be a security/authentication issue.  There are a few simple things you can do to check that:

- If you have authentication attributes set on your controllers or methods, try commenting them out
- try commenting out any other authentication code

If that doesn't fix it, then when you've got the app running in debug, try using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to call your remote validation endpoint and see whether:

- Postman gets a 200 back from your method.
- If so, put a breakpoint in your code and check it is actually getting executed.

If Postman can get to your endpoint then...

#### Is there an issue in your code?

I can't see anything obviously wrong in your code, but it is different to how I write validation code.  This is an example of some working remote validation straight out of my code

This is the model property with the remote validation set:

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote(
        action: "CheckExistingDocumentCode",
        controller: "Documents",
        AdditionalFields = "DocumentId",
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        ErrorMessage = "Code already exists")]
    public string DocumentCode { get; set; }
```

This is the corresponding method in the Documents controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CheckExistingDocumentCode(string DocumentCode, int DocumentId)
{
    try
    {
        if (!await _documentValidationRules.IsExistingDocumentCodeAsync(DocumentCode, DocumentId))
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json("This Document Code is already in use", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

You can see that I've explicitly named all the parameters on the model property just to be clear exactly what's going on.

Comparing my code to yours the main differences are:

- Mines async.  That shouldn't make any difference.
- My contrller method is a POST (so is has the `HttpPost` attribute, which also means I needed to tell the model the `HttpMethod` was POST too)
- My remote validation method takes two parameters, so I'm passing in an extra property via the `AdditionalFields` argument

I can't see what the issue is in your code, but try changing it a piece at a time to work more like mine (particularly, try making it a post method and naming the parameters) and see if that exposes any issues.

Hopefully something in the above will get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the thing is I used Global authentication in program.cs,just use AllowAnonymous Annotation on IsEmailExist(), it will work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34860461)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing the following:

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing no one mentioned which will cause your symptons: If the method needs to be executed by Anonymous users and you don't have the AllowAnonymous attribute on your method, the method will not fire (and the submit button won't do anything.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add this code to the bottom of your View:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

This is the issue I had.

Answer (score -1):

```
//[AcceptVerbs("Get,Post")]
//[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> IsEmailInUse(string email)
{
  var registration = await 
  _context.Registration.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Email == email);
   if(registration == null)
    {
      return Json(true);
    }
    else
    {
     return Json($"Email {email} is already in use");
    }
 }

//In Model Class
public class Registration
{
 [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
  public int EmpId { get; set; }

  public string UserName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [EmailAddress]

  [Remote(action: "IsEmailInUse",controller: "Registrations")]
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).